# Как сделать генерацию чисел от 0 до 1

Tags: java

Как сделать генерацию чисел от 0 до 1. Если выпадет 0 то человек победил и в консоле выводит это. Если 1 то он проиграл и так же пишет в консоле java.

Comment: Можно просто сразу использовать [`new Random().nextBoolean()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/random_nextboolean.htm).

Comment: А если выпадет 0,3?

Comment: Имею ввиду int. Только 0 и 1 может выпасть.

Answer (score 2):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int i = rand.nextInt(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Классика

```java
int i = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
System.out.println(i);
```

**Тест**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 100_000_000; n++) {
            int i = (int) (Math.random() * 2);

            if (i != 1 && i !=0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @freim добавил тест. Вроде не падает.